# XMLHttpRequest API display in Table that updates

Tags: javascript, html, json, xml, api

I'm trying to create a table that displays the estimated time of arrival for ships arriving to a port. I'm calling the API:

```
https://services.marinetraffic.com/api/expectedarrivals/v:3/apikey/portid:DKKAL/protocol:xml/timespan:1
```

which gives me the response that I want to display in a table in HTML, that updates whenever a new ship is supposedly arriving to the port:

```
<ETA>
 <VESSEL_ETA MMSI="21840000" ETA="2018-10-03T08:00:00"/>
</ETA>
```

So far this is what I've got:

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">SHIPS</button>
<table id="ships"></table>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myFunction(this);
  }
 };

  xhttp.open("GET","https://services.marinetraffic.com/api/expectedarrivals/v:3/apikey/portid:DKKAL/protocol:xml/timespan:1", true);
  xhttp.send();
 }
 function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>MMSI</th><th>ETA</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ETA");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("MMSI")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("ETA")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("ships").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>
```

However nothing is displayed except for the table headers. How do I make it display the xml response, and make it update whenever a new ship is added to the list?

Comment: check your browsers **developer** tools console for any errors

Comment: but first ... you have a function called `loadDoc` ... but it's never actually called in the code you posted - perhaps that's the issue

Comment: My bad, had a button that called the function, that I forgot in the main post. Added it now.

Comment: no, that's OK, as long as you are actually calling the function (common mistake, believe it or not!!!)

Comment: can you show an example of the response? as you need an API key, it's not possible for just anyone to see the response :p

Comment: Your response is returning ​<RESPONSE><STATUS><ERROR CODE="10" DESCRIPTION="SERVICE KEY NOT FOUND"/></STATUS></RESPONSE>

Comment: Yes, the response is also in the main post.
    <ETA><VESSEL_ETA MMSI="21840000" ETA="2018-10-03T08:00:00"/></ETA>

Comment: d'oh ... I didn't see that at all (the response) - I'm too old for this :p

Comment: is `<ETA>` the root of the document?

Comment: Yes in the response

Comment: well, check the browser developer tools console for errors in that case - because your code wont run as is

Comment: as far as I can see, you should be `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("VESSEL_ETA")` ... and `x[i].getAttribute('MMSI')` and `x[i].getAttribute('ETA')` - not sure what it looks like when there's more than one ship in the result (could you show that, perhaps)

Comment: Apparently it can't read the MMSI in   x[i].getElementsByTagName("MMSI")

Comment: @JaromandaX getAttribute worked! When should I be using getElementsByTagName? Thank you so much!

Comment: getElementsByTagName ... returns descendant NODES ... getAttribute returns an attribute of a NODE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're processing the XML incorrectly

The nodes you are looking for are VESSEL_ETA, not ETA

and the MSSI/ETA are attributes of those nodes, not child nodes

so

```html
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">SHIPS</button>
<table id="ships"></table>

<script>
    // this is a dummied up loadDoc - which has no errors in the question
    // this calls myFunction with a dummied up XMLHttpRequest response
    function loadDoc() {
        let rawxml = `<ETA>
 <VESSEL_ETA MMSI="21840000" ETA="2018-10-03T08:00:00"/>
</ETA>`;
        var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(rawxml, 'text/xml');
        myFunction({responseXML: xmlDoc});
    }
    
    function myFunction(xml) {
        var i;
        var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        var table="<tr><th>MMSI</th><th>ETA</th></tr>";
        var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("VESSEL_ETA");
        for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
            table += '<tr><td>' + 
                x[i].getAttribute('MMSI') + 
                '</td><td>' + 
                x[i].getAttribute('ETA') + 
                '</td></tr>';
        }
        document.getElementById("ships").innerHTML = table;
    }
</script>
```